# How to solve this six variables of simultaneous equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, integer-programming

The problems is:

$A^2+D^2=5$

$B^2+E^2=2$

$C^2+F^2=6$

$AB+DE=3$

$BC+EF=1$

$AC+DF=1$

Please tell me what is the roots for this simultaneous equation, no process or just solve it by calculator are both fine to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce to three unknowns $x,y,z$ making $$A=\sqrt5\sin(x),\space D=\sqrt5\cos(x)\\B=\sqrt2\sin(y),\space E=\sqrt2\cos(y)\\C=\sqrt6\sin(z),\space F=\sqrt6\cos(z)\\AB+DE=\sqrt{10}\cos(x-y)=3\\BC+EF=\sqrt{12}\cos(y-z)=1\\AC+DF=\sqrt{30}\cos(x-z)=1$$ This gives $$\arccos\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\right)=x-y\approx0.3217505\\\arccos\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\right)=y-z\approx1.2779535\\\arccos\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{30}}\right)=z-x\approx1.3871923$$
So you can verify that there is not solution to your system.

Comment: Maybe $x-y=2kπ +0.321$....

Comment: No, what you get immediately is the incompatibility of the values found.

Comment: +1 for your nice answer but $\sqrt{10} \cos(t)=3$ does not mean $t=\arccos(3/\sqrt{10})$....

Comment: unless you want to mean the following: $x-y=2aπ+β$,  $y-z=2bπ+γ$, $z-x=2cπ+δ$, where $a,b,c$ are integers and $\vert β\vert=\arccos3/\sqrt{10}$, $\vert γ\vert=\arccos1/\sqrt{12}$, $\vert δ\vert=\arccos1/\sqrt{30}$. Adding them we get $\vert β\vert+\vert γ\vert+\vert δ\vert=2λπ$ , where $λ$ is integer, which is imposible....

Comment: @dmtri.- In particular, the given values are valid and it was not a matter of finding these values but of exhibiting the incompatibility of the system of equations.

Answer (score 2):

There is no triple of (real) vectors in $\mathbb R^2$   with the desired Gram matrix; the angles

There are triples of real vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ it can be done, not with integers. The quick proof is simply that the Gram matrix has determinant $5,$ not a square number.

Finally, this arrangement exists with integer coordinates in $\mathbb R^4,$
the basis vectors are the rows of
$$
B = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
G = BB^T = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
5 & 3 & 1  \\
3 & 2 & 1  \\
1 & 1 & 6  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

I obtain, for the RHS equal to $2$,
$$
A=\sqrt{2 - F^2}, \; 
B=\sqrt{2-F^2},\;
C=\sqrt{2- F^2},\;
D=E=F,
$$
or the negative square roots. So $A=B=C$ and $D=E=F$.

The edited problem has no solution (for RHS $5,2,6,3,1,1$).

Comment: Thank you, but I edited the problem,  please help me to solve the edited problem.

Comment: What I want is (5,2,6,3,1,1), and you mean there are no roots for this constraint?

Comment: Please also tell me which program you use, thank you.

Comment: I compute a Gröbner basis. Where do your equations come from?